# Signed exe displays uknown publisher on Win7 only

Tags: windows, visual-studio, code-signing

I have a .NET application I am trying to sign with a Comodo cert. I am using the following to sign my program.

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\kSign\signtool.exe" sign /f "E:\repos\NGS Code     Signing Cert 2015.pfx" /p XXXXXX /fd sha1 /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com /d "test program" /du "http://www.mywebsitesoftware.com" "E:\repos\i2x.net\MSI Setups\i2xInstaller\bin\Release\test.exe"
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe" sign /f "E:\repos\NGS Code Signing Cert 2015.pfx" /p XXXXXX /fd sha256 /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 /d "test program" /du "http://www.mywebsitesoftware.com" "E:\repos\i2x.net\MSI Setups\i2xInstaller\bin\Release\test.exe"

This works fine and dual signs the EXE. This can be verified by check the program properties and you can see the digital signatures. The problem is that Windows 7 x64 shows the digital signatures but when running as admin shows 'Unknown publisher' (I have tested this on 3 different machines that are fully up to date)

It DOES works fine in Windows Server 2008, 2012, 2016 and Windows 8.1 and 10.

Has anyone else seen this before?
Thanks

Comment: Did you read this? https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO26221&actp=RSS&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Yes I did, Both my test machines have KB3033929 installed.

Comment: The problem was incomplete Windows updates of my both test VM's and on my bosses test machine. Once the machines where FULLY updated (and that took 6 or 7 times of forcing Windows to update and it did not matter if the Microsoft KB3033929 that included the SHA256 support was installed) the things started working.

Comment: Post that As an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was incomplete Windows updates of my both test VM's and on my bosses test machine. Once the machines where FULLY updated (and that took 6 or 7 times of forcing Windows to update and it did not matter if the Microsoft KB3033929 that included the SHA256 support was installed) the things started working.